# How to pull value from another sheet in excel?

Tags: excel, indexing

I have two sheets-
"Employee" and "Salary"

In **Salary** Sheet, in 'E3' cell I want to set value from 'S4' cell of **Employee** sheet.That mean whatever data in 'S4' of Employee Sheet will be set in 'E3' in Salary

I think it is simple but I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=Employee!S4`

In general, it'll be the sheet name followed by ! followed by the cell lookup. If the sheet name has spaces it will need to be wrapped in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

you can start writing the formula and when you need the cell from the other sheet just go with the mouse to the relevant sheet and choose the required cell, Excel will write the name of the path in the formula for you...